# Is there a way to pass a texture to the Metal shader referenced in the .colorEffect view modifier in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, metal

I need to create an effect in a SwiftUI UI that involves lookups in 2D and 3D tables. I am a Metal newbee so my intention is to keep it as simple as possible.

I am currently wondering if I can use the swiftUI .colorEffect view modifier and a stichable shader in Metal to achieve that?

There are a few argument types to Shader which could in theory transport the data of the texture into the shader, but I suspect that this does not cut it, does it? (As I need a texture in a buffer to sample it and I doubt this can be set up in a shader?)

I will probably need to set up my own pipline, create a descriptor of sort that needs to be passed into the command encoder etc, etc... (I am learning... ) and render to a MTKView? Correct?

Or is there in fact an easier way?